# How to compare Hour and Minute only from DateTime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime-format

I have field endTime has DateTime data type and status (int). I want to update my status field from 1 to 0 if hour and minute from endTime is equal to hour and minute of current time. the day is absolutely same. so the day is doesn't matter.

How do I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datepart()`:

```
select (case when datepart(hour, EndTime) = datepart(hour, getdate()) and
                  datepart(minute, EndTime) = datepart(minute, getdate())
             then 1 else 0
        end) as status
```

You can also put this into an update, if that is what you really want.

EDIT:
The update would be:

```
update table
    set status = (case when datepart(hour, EndTime) = datepart(hour, getdate()) and
                            datepart(minute, EndTime) = datepart(minute, getdate())
                       then 1 else 0
                  end);
```

Comment: I think the 1 and 0 need to switch around?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE <table> SET status = 0
WHERE datepart(hour, endTime) = datepart(hour,getdate())
AND datepart(minute, endTime) = datepart(minute,getdate());
```

This is How I do on my SQL-Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE <TABLE> 
SET STATUS = 1
WHERE MINUTE(GETDATE()) = MINUTE(ENDTIME)
   AND HOUR(GETDATE()) = HOUR(ENDTIME)
```